# Copy data from csv to excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am very new to Python.

I have 1000 CSV files, same data type in each(around 10k data point in each).
Want to copy all data point from a CSV to a template excel files where all graphs and calculations are tailored in. Then save that files as a new excel file with csv file name, keeping template file as it is.

```
import csv
import openpyxl
for x in range(1,2):
    f = open("ver20_RUN" + str(x) + ".csv", "r")
    f_con = csv.reader(f)
    f_data = []
    for row in f_con:
        if len (row) != 0:
            f_data = f_data + [row]
    f.close()
    wb =openpyxl.load_workbook("tmp.xlsx")
    sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    sheet['A1'] = f_data # I cant figure how I can copy data from f_data to Sheet1
    wb.save("result" + str(x) + ".xlsx")
```

Is there any fast way to do it seeing the large amount of data.

thanks

Comment: Yes there is. This sadly not the type of question that is answered in SO. This is not a code writing service but rather a sound board to bounce off code you have created and get assistance in resolving targeted issues. Please attempt to find a solution and then revisit here to post your question with sample code. Regards.

Comment: Okay yes, I get it. I made a code and have added it in question now.

Comment: If you only need to do this once try just opening the CSV file with excel and then copying the data to where you need it.

Comment: Yes I need to do exactly that, but just 1000 times

Comment: So you want to turn 10,000 CSV files into 10,000 Excel files, each one that is already filled with calculations?  Have you considered doing the calculations and graphs in Python instead?  That's an environment that handles iteration very naturally, whereas Excel does not.  Seems like you might be making more work and hassle for yourself this way.

Comment: Actually, my plan is to extract a value from all final excel files, after all this is done. I have a working code for that.
As I am not good with Python, doing calculations and graphs would be more hassle for me. This way I would have complete set of scripts which I can use anytime, just have to make a template excel file